# symantec.itools.awt.shape.Rect & symantec.itools.awt.ImagePanel

Tags: java

In Java when I do

```
import symantec.itools.awt.shape.Rect;
import symantec.itools.awt.ImagePanel;
```

and when I call

```
Rect rects[] = new Rect[256];
```

I get an error cause I don't have that library? How I could handle that problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the required library to the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Comment: I could not find that library:(

Comment: You can't use a library you don't have.

Comment: There must be a reason why you are typing in these import statements. You didn't just invent them. So... where did you find them?

Comment: I am using open source code. Thats why i need it

Comment: http://www.oracle-java.com/article/6171760/symantec+itools+%3F It seems this library is a part of Visual Cafe IDE. And half of the Internet is looking for it since 1999.

Comment: I still have the same problem. Is there any way to solve that issue?